Export Python charts excel with grid layout
I'm trying to write a Python script that generates a series of charts from Excel. The Excel file has the price of different cars on each day.
Column 1 is the Date; Column 2 is price for Green cars; Column 3 is the price for Red cars etc. The following code only outputs graphs for the first and last columns (first column being a car price and not the date column) and the two graphs are spaced apart. For example first chart is displayed in column D and the second chart in column AFD.
How can I amend my code so that it appears in a nice grid format (two graphs per row)?
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xlsxwriter
import io

def generate_seasonal_charts(file_path, start_date, end_date, output_file):

    df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

    df = df[(df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date)]

    df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output_file)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    # Define image dimensions and positions
    image_width = 800
    image_height = 400
    x_offset = 0
    y_offset = 0
    y_spacing = image_height + 20

    # Create charts for each column
    for i, column in enumerate(df.columns[1:]):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
        ax.plot(df.index, df[column])
        ax.set_xlabel('Date')
        ax.set_ylabel('Value')
        ax.set_title(f'Seasonal Data for {column}')
        plt.grid(True)

        # Save the plot to a buffer
        buf = io.BytesIO()
        fig.savefig(buf, format='png')    
        buf.seek(0)

        # Embed the image in the Excel worksheet
        if i == 0:
            worksheet.insert_image(x_offset, y_offset, f"Chart {i+1}",     {'image_data': buf, 'x_scale': image_width / fig.canvas.get_width_height()[0],     'y_scale': image_height / fig.canvas.get_width_height()[1]})
        else:
            y_offset += y_spacing
            worksheet.insert_image(x_offset, y_offset, f"Chart {i+1}",     {'image_data': buf, 'x_scale': image_width / fig.canvas.get_width_height()[0], 'y_scale': image_height / fig.canvas.get_width_height()[1]})

        plt.close(fig)

    workbook.close()

    file_path = "chart testing.xlsx"
    output_file = "output.xlsx"
    start_date = '2018-01-01'
    end_date = '2023-12-31'

    generate_seasonal_charts(file_path, start_date, end_date, output_file)


What do you mean by column AFD? if you want a grid of plots you should also update x_offset. And the condition on i doesn't seem necessary: y_offset = y_offset + i * y_spacing ?

Without seeing the input file it's hard to tell exactly what might be the issue. One thing that stood out right away is this part of your code:
  workbook.close()

  file_path = "chart testing.xlsx"
  output_file = "output.xlsx"
  start_date = '2018-01-01'
  end_date = '2023-12-31'

  generate_seasonal_charts(file_path, start_date, end_date, output_file)

The first four lines after workbook.close() seem to be things you intended on running in a main function before calling generate_seasonal_charts with the parameters. I can't say for sure as I don't understand the context of this code, but this seems like an unintended indent.
  workbook.close()

# main function definition
def main():
    file_path = "chart testing.xlsx"
    output_file = "output.xlsx"
    start_date = '2018-01-01'
    end_date = '2023-12-31'

    generate_seasonal_charts(file_path, start_date, end_date, output_file)

# main function call
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

